# ArcGIS Viewer for Flex - map won't display in preview tab

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, map-service, arcgis-flex-viewer

I'm new to ArcGIS Viewer for Flex and ArcGIS for Server, so far I have been able to get past the point where I get to choose my base map and operational layers from the ArcGIS for Server 10.2. I can see my map on the map extent tab, but when I go to the preview tab, all I see is information about the layers and other stuffs in the service directory. I am unable to see the map itself. I am using ArcGIS Viewer for Flex 3.6.

### My setting page

web server base folder: - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\flexviewers
web server base folder url: - \http:/loc:6020/arcgis/rest/services/Jegol_web_mapping_trial/MapServer

### My map page

I called the map from the same page as the web server base folder URL which is : - \http://loc:6020/arcgis/rest/services/Jegol_web_mapping_trial/MapServer

I don't seem to find where I made the mistake, can anyone help me out please

Comment: I know when I originally was playing with the FlexViewer that I had cross-domain issues.  Try opening your webpage/application in a web browser like Chrome and check the developer tools.  You can check the network part of those and see if there are issues getting the map layers.

Comment: Just because this mentions your new to the ArcGIS Viewer for Flex, I strongly encourage you to take a look at the ArcGIS Web Appbuilder.  It was released today into ArcGIS Online, but you can also download a standalone developer edition.  Flex is dying, and the Web AppBuilder caters for mobile audiences.  If your keen, ill convert this into an answer with more info. http://www.esri.com/software/web-appbuilder